# Associate Professor position I applied for changed the selection criteria after 3 stage process

Tags: publications, conference, faculty-application, interview

Recently, I applied for an associate professor position in a high rank university. I cleared 3 stages, document screening, presentation/lecture, and a long interview. But, I received a rejection email stating that I have so many Journal publications but I don’t have enough conference publications. It is really disappointing that they already cleared me during document screening, and this is something they should have told me during first stage. The rejection email didn’t say anything about presentation/lecture or interview.
Should I ask them to give a better reason or feedback on interview? Or should I ask them for the compensation for wasting my time, I travelled 250KM twice.

Comment: Rejection emails nearly always have no useful information in them.

Answer (score 7):

You seem to be very angry. Obviously, it is a very bad idea to contact them as long as you feel that way. Take some time off to let this cool down before you do anything with it.

As to the reason they gave for rejecting you: If this was a good university, then they probably had multiple good candidates to choose from. You were apparently one of those good candidates and you can feel good about that. It is easy to find a good reason when choosing between a good and a bad candidate. Finding a good reason to differentiate between two or more good candidates is a lot harder. That is when small differences start to matter. I guess that is what happened in your case.

"should I ask them for the compensation for wasting my time" You voluntarily chose to invest your time and money for a *chance* to get that job. If they offered beforehand to pay for example travel costs, then by all means, take it. If they did not offer it, and you still applied, then it was your choice to gamble that time and money. This time, the gamble did not pay off. That can happen when you gamble...

Comment: Regarding travel costs: This is called an "opportunity cost", https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunity_cost

Answer (score 3):

> they already cleared me during document screening, and this is something they should have told me during first stage.

You seem to be assuming that the document screening was pass/fail, and you passed, and so your documents should never have been considered again.

But here's another scenario: on the basis of your document screening, you were ranked second or third. The top three candidates were then invited for an interview, where your good performance (or another candidate's poor performance) might have changed this ranking. But all three candidates interviewed well, and so the rankings were unchanged.

> The rejection email didn’t say anything about presentation/lecture or interview. Should I ask them to give a better reason or feedback on interview?

This is exactly why most rejection letters just say "thank you for your time; unfortunately, we chose someone else." It is very kind of the department to take the time to give you individualized feedback. It is absolutely not an invitation to second-guess or debate their decision.

> Or should I ask them for the compensation for wasting my time, I travelled 250KM twice.

If you go on a date but don't get a second date, would you send them a bill for wasting your time? Better to assume that you got a fair shot and it didn't work out. Better luck next time.

Answer (score 0):

While it is annoying not to get a job you really wanted, the basic fact is that we do not have a *right* to be hired by anyone even if we think that we are well qualified.

As a consequence, you can complain all day long, but the complaints are not going to change the basic facts that the university decided not to hire you because, presumably, they found someone who on balance of all criteria considered, was a better fit for what they wanted. Any complaints can only have one result: That you are considered unreasonable in your community, and that you are burning bridges you might want to keep.